# How to balance the storage of state between redux store and Class state

Tags: redux

All:

I am pretty new to Redux, React-redux and React, one concept I learn about Redux is single store.

I kinda having some difficulty to determine where to store data when use React with Redux, what kind of data I should store in Component Class state, and what should store in Redux store?

Any simple example will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you divide up your state is entirely up to you.  A recent [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4w04to/when_using_redux_should_all_asynchronous_actions/d63u4o8) has some pretty good rules of thumb:

> - Do other parts of the application care about that list?
> - Do you need to be able to derive data from that list?
> - Is the same data being used to drive multiple components/features
> - Is there value to you, to being able to restore the state to a given point in time (ie: time travel / debugging)
> - Do you want to cache the data, ie: reload it from state if it's already there instead of requesting it again?
>
> Not /everything/ needs to go into your global app state. There can be benefits to putting every-last bit of thing into your state, but there can also be complications.

The Redux FAQ also discusses this topic: http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state